# shell script not being invoked via php and completion status running shell script in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, shell

I am using php to control(start/stop) my servers. Inside php I am using shell_exec, which runs shell script and start/stop the server. Following is the code for button and further action upon button click.

```
<table><tr><td>Server1</td><td><form method="post"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" name ="start_as" value="start"/>
</form>
<?php
function startAS()
{
shell_exec("/$path/startASServer.sh");
}
if(array_key_exists('start_as',$_POST)){
   startAS();
}
?>
</td></tr></table>
```

and below my sh file:

```
ssh user@ip "nohup /$path/startASServer.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
SERVER=ip1 PORT=port1
while !(: < /dev/tcp/$SERVER/$PORT) 2>/dev/null
do
    echo "* Waiting for  Server to Start *"
done
echo "Server is Started"
```

The problem is when I click on "start" button, the browser hangs and  I can not see shell script being run on server, request expert guidance here. Also, if there is anyway wherein I can show two updates in popup window showing task started and task completed.

Thanks

Comment: Does the script work fine if you run it manually from your terminal (not from PHP)? If the browser hangs, probably, the `while` loop in your script doesn't end and you need to check the script at first

Comment: Hi Fogus, I checked the script and it works perfectly fine from terminal. The while does end when it finds ip:port and exits.

Comment: Is this an exact version of the code you have on your end? Because I see there is an error: `$path` is not available in `startAS`

Comment: Thanks for updates, path is just place holder here, I am using absolute path actually and it works. I will modify my script here to avoid confusion. Thanks

Comment: I think adding more output can help you detect the issue. If the script for some reason dies, `shell_exec` doesn't not return the output. You need to call `exec` (or other similar function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to see its result.

Comment: Also I assume there can be an error related to ssh: if you use an SSH key stored in your `~/.ssh`, i.e. do not provide a password in the line `ssh user@ip "nohup ...`, then another user may not have access to this key. Remember, when you run some code from browser, the code is executed by a server (nginx/apache) and the server does it as another user, `www-data` or smth like this. You may run the shell script as from this user: `sudo su www-data` (but check if this is really `www-data`, e.g. `shell_exec('whoami')`)

Comment: Hi Fogus, thanks for inputs, I tried with exec but no output. shell_exec('whoami') output is daemon, so I guess it is not able to run remote scripts(php is able to run shell scripts though on same server where php and weserver are installed.). I actually can not install ssh2 lib on this server and needed something which can actually help running scripts on remote servers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209708/discussion-between-fogus-and-novice).